# Why datagridview adds additional 2 blank rows when the bounded datatable only adds 1 row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I am using vb.net 2010. I have a datagridview whose data source is a data table. I dynamically add rows to the data table.

```
Friend WithEvents DGVCusClient As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

      DGVCusClient.DataSource = m_table


      Private Sub DVGCusClient_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DGVCusClient.DoubleClick

      Dim newRow As DataRow = m_table.NewRow()

      newRow.Item(colNameCustomer) = "Customer Name"

      newRow.Item(colNameClient) = "Client Name"

     m_table.Rows.Add(newRow)
    End Sub
```

After adding the new row, m_table is correct. However, DVGCusClient not only adds this row, but also adds two additional blank rows at the bottom. I have no idea where these two blank rows come from.

Why I use above code is as follows:

Use a data grid view to display data. When a user clicks a row, another form is opened which allows user to search/input some data.When the user closes the form, all data is saved to a data table and shown on the data grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its adding additional row because of this line: m_table.Rows.Add(newRow)

Because newRow.item will add new row to the table